# VB.net error in designer.

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am getting this error message "The class pnlOne can be designed, but is not the first class in the file. Visual Studio requires that designers use the first class in the file. Move the class code so that it is the first class in the file and try loading the designer again. " By code is below. I copied it from some C# code I found.

```
Namespace MetroPanelSlide.Panel

Partial Public Class pnlOne
    Inherits pnlSlider
    Implements IMetroControl

    Private Sub pnlOne_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(owner As Form)
        MyBase.New(owner)

        Me.StyleManager.Update()
    End Sub


End Class
End Namespace
```

C# code is:

```
namespace MetroPanelSlide.Panel
{
public partial class pnlOne : pnlSlider, IMetroControl
{
    public pnlOne(Form owner) : base(owner)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.StyleManager.Update();
    }

    private void pnlOne_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is that the only class in your file?

Comment: Yes this is only class I have

Comment: Well, surely you used the *partial* keyword for a reason, look in the other source code file(s).

Answer (score -1):

Found out the issue. Thank you all. I found the other class it was referencing.